# How to improve performance of items selection in C# Linq (Large collection)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, left-join

1. I have a large collection of objects (eg. 100 000)
2. These objects do not have indexes or any information about their size or location
3. If no custom height is defined, each object has a default height (e.g., 30)
4. For each element (according to the index) a custom height can be defined
5. It is important that the objects are in the **IList** collection

Providing current Top and Height, I would like to get objects located in this area. Based on the items position on the list, default/custom height and scene definition.
I prepared a solution, but unfortunately it is inefficient.
Can you help me to improve performance?

**My inefficient funcion:**

```
static List<int> GetIndexes(double y, double sceneHeight)
    {               
        int index1 = 0;     
        var dataIndexed = (from d in Data.Cast<object>() select new { Index = index1++});//IList casting Data.Cast<object>()                

        double top = 0;
        double height = 0;  
        int index2 = 0;

        var xr = (from di in dataIndexed
                  join definition in Definitions on di.Index equals definition.Index into X
                  from x in X.DefaultIfEmpty()                    
                  select new
                  {
                      Index = index2++,
                      Top = top += height,
                      Height = height = (x == null ? DefaultHeight : x.Height) //Default or Custom height

                  });                   
        return (from i in xr where i.Top >= y && i.Top < y + sceneHeight select i.Index).ToList();          
    }
```

**My custom object definition:**

```
public class ItemDefinition
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public static void Main()
    {
        CreateData();
        CreateDefinitions();            
        double expectedTop = 30;        
        double expectedHeight = 201;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        List<int> indexes = GetIndexes(expectedTop, expectedHeight);
        Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
        foreach(int index in indexes)
            Console.WriteLine(index);
    }
```

[Live Demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/frANWi)

Comment: He is one improvement : var dataIndexed = (new string('a', Data.Count)).Select((x, i) => new { Index = i });

Comment: Sorry but i am confused, but why do you need two different lists if you join them anyway?

Comment: The first list (Data) comes from outside and I can not change it (IList), the second list stores custom heights.